# SQL: How to calculate a cumulative sum that resets per time slot and name?

Tags: sql, database, db2, aggregate-functions

Let's suppose I have the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE transaction (
  "ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  "NAME" VARCHAR(4),
  "TIMESTAMP" INTEGER,
  "QUANTITY" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO transaction
  ("ID", "NAME", "TIMESTAMP", "QUANTITY")
VALUES
  ('1', 'dani', '1686311907', '1'),
  ('2', 'dani', '1686312071', '4'),
  ('3', 'dani', '1686748928', '2'),
  ('4', 'pet', '1687937005', '2'),
  ('5', 'pet', '1688109281', '6');
```

Which corresponds to:

```
| ID  | NAME | TIMESTAMP  | QUANTITY |
| --- | ---- | ---------- | -------- |
| 1   | dani | 1686311907 | 1        |
| 2   | dani | 1686312071 | 4        |
| 3   | dani | 1686748928 | 2        |
| 4   | pet  | 1687937005 | 2        |
| 5   | pet  | 1688109281 | 6        |
```

This table describes a series of transactions. In general, what I want is, for each name and for each timestamp, to calculate a cumulative sum of the quantities within each working slot. Each working slot will include those timestamps that are within a time interval of less than 10800 seconds (equivalent to 3 hours). In other words, the cumulative sum must be reset, for each name, on each working slot.

What I would expect to get would be a table like the following:

```
| ID  | NAME | TIMESTAMP  | QUANTITY | CUM_QUANTITY |
| --- | ---- | ---------- | -------- | ------------
| 1   | dani | 1686311907 | 1        | 1            |
| 2   | dani | 1686312071 | 4        | 5            |
| 3   | dani | 1686748928 | 2        | 2            | # new working slot
| 4   | pet  | 1687937005 | 2        | 2            | # new name
| 5   | pet  | 1688109281 | 6        | 6            | # new working slot
```

So far I've tried to add a transitional column to check if the record belongs to a new day:

```
select 
  *, 
  CASE WHEN coalesce(
    "TIMESTAMP" - lag("TIMESTAMP", 1) over (
      partition by "NAME" 
      order by 
        "TIMESTAMP" asc
    ), 
    0
  ) < 3600 * 3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS NEW_DAY 
from 
  transaction 
ORDER BY 
  "NAME", 
  "TIMESTAMP"
```

Which give us the following table:

```
| ID  | NAME | TIMESTAMP  | QUANTITY | new_day |
| --- | ---- | ---------- | -------- | ------- |
| 1   | dani | 1686311907 | 1        | 0       |
| 2   | dani | 1686312071 | 4        | 0       |
| 3   | dani | 1686748928 | 2        | 1       |
| 4   | pet  | 1687937005 | 2        | 0       |
| 5   | pet  | 1688109281 | 6        | 1       |
```

And then perform some kind of window by using NAME and new_day and aggregating by SUM(QUANTITY), but this approach doesn't work because new_day only takes the values 0 and 1, and it should take from 0, 1, ... to the maximum working slots per user.

Does anybody know how to proceed?

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer the [OLAP specification](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=expressions-olap-specification) topic on the `RANGE` OLAP function use.

```
WITH transaction ("ID", "NAME", "TIMESTAMP", "QUANTITY") AS 
(
VALUES
  (1, 'dani', 1686311907, 1),
  (2, 'dani', 1686312071, 4),
  (3, 'dani', 1686748928, 2),
  (4, 'pet',  1687937005, 2),
  (5, 'pet',  1688109281, 6)
)
SELECT 
  * 
, sum ("QUANTITY") over (partition by "NAME" order by "TIMESTAMP" range between 10800 preceding and current row)
  as CUM_QUANTITY
FROM transaction
```

| ID | NAME | TIMESTAMP | QUANTITY | CUM_QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dani | 1686311907 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | dani | 1686312071 | 4 | 5 |
| 3 | dani | 1686748928 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | pet | 1687937005 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | pet | 1688109281 | 6 | 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/c8iKIxtR)

**Update:**
With the `WORKING_SLOT` artificial column.
Its computation inside of each name is based on:

- calculation of "flag" value for each row - 0 when a difference between current and last timestamp is less then 3 hours and 1 otherwise
- cumulative sum of these flags

The result is the same on this dataset, but may be different on others.

```
WITH 
transaction ("ID", "NAME", "TIMESTAMP", "QUANTITY") AS 
(
VALUES
  (1, 'dani', 1686311907, 1),
  (2, 'dani', 1686312071, 4),
  (3, 'dani', 1686748928, 2),
  (4, 'pet',  1687937005, 2),
  (5, 'pet',  1688109281, 6)
)
, transaction_with_working_slot AS 
(
SELECT 
  * 
, SUM 
(
  CASE 
    WHEN "TIMESTAMP" - COALESCE (LAG ("TIMESTAMP") OVER (PARTITION BY "NAME" ORDER BY "TIMESTAMP"), 0) < 10800
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END
) OVER (PARTITION BY "NAME" ORDER BY "TIMESTAMP")
  AS WORKING_SLOT
FROM transaction
)
SELECT 
  *
, SUM ("QUANTITY") OVER (PARTITION BY "NAME", "WORKING_SLOT" ORDER BY "TIMESTAMP")
  AS CUM_QUANTITY
FROM transaction_with_working_slot
ORDER BY "NAME", "TIMESTAMP"
```

| ID | NAME | TIMESTAMP | QUANTITY | WORKING_SLOT | CUM_QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dani | 1686311907 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | dani | 1686312071 | 4 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | dani | 1686748928 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | pet | 1687937005 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | pet | 1688109281 | 6 | 2 | 6 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/omu5ncsD)

Comment: Nice answer. It works! But still missing the WORKING_SLOT. I tried to add it in the last SELECT as follows:
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "NAME" ORDER BY "TIMESTAMP" RANGE BETWEEN 10800 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS WORKING_SLOT` but this throws an exception: An unexpected token "RANGE" was found following "<OLAP window specification>".  Expected tokens may include:  ")".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.26.14. Do you know why is this happening? I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: The solution doesn't use your "working slot" term because of its vague description. The rule used here is: "sum the current value with all previous if they are within the range of timestamps specified relative to this current record". There are no working slots here. Consider 3 (or even more) rows with the same name and difference of 10800 - 1 between each one. What would be the slot enumeration scheme here? Do they all get the same slot number? If yes, then the query in the answer is not correct and must be rewritten.

Comment: In that case, the working_slot would increase by one each time there is a minimum difference of 10800 between adjacent rows (ordering by timestamp). Something like an accumulative sum of the table I posted above

Comment: @Dani I've updated the answer. Please, check it.